# How to filter a DataFrame column of lists for those that contain a certain item

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If I want to filter a column of strings for those that contain a certain term I can do so like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['ab','ac','abc']})
df[df['col'].str.contains('b')]
```

returns:

```
   col
0   ab
2  abc
```

How can I filter a column of lists for those that contain a certain item? For example, from

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['a','b'],['a','c'],['a','b','c']]})
```

how can I get all lists containing 'b'?

```
         col
0     [a, b]
2  [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use apply, like this.

```
In [13]: df[df['col'].apply(lambda x: 'b' in x)]
Out[13]: 
         col
0     [a, b]
2  [a, b, c]
```

Although generally, storing lists in a `DataFrame` is a bit awkward - you might find some different representation (columns for each element in the list, MultiIndex, etc) that is easier to work with.

Comment: @chrisb How would you deal if you have a large `DataFrame` and you don't know the number of entries (or want to avoid a very high number of columns)?

Comment: Its an either or situation.  Either you use lists in a column which has its pros and cons or you use multi/one-hot encoding and have # of columns equal to the unique elements of all your lists in the column.  This may not be a problem depending on your purpose.  You can easily check for inclusion with many columns without a major hit in performance.

Comment: apply is so slow, what is alternative for apply?