# filter DataFrame leaving rows where Needle is part of the list present in columnB

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a filter function on my DataFrame to find rows where my searchTerm is in the list that is in the dataframe row.

I've been digging trough list related filters, they all seem to have a 'list' as needles and a single value in the dataFrame column.

```python
df = pd.DataFrame({'groups':['SportsMen','FisherMen','Students','OutdoorTypes'],'members':[['a','b'],['b'],['a'],['FisherMen','c']]})
```

Now i need to get a filtered set (preferably a clone) where 'b' is a member. In my final solution I'll have to recursively do this so I would also find
'b' is member of 'Fisherman' and thereby member of 'OutdoorTypes'

Answer (score 0):

[How to filter a DataFrame column of lists for those that contain a certain item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280556/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-column-of-lists-for-those-that-contain-a-certain-item)

contains the solution:

```
df[df['members'].apply(lambda x: 'b' in x)]
```