# How manage filter rows by colum-list Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataset in which one column corresponds to a list of hashtags, and I want to select the rows that have "#tourism" inside that column.

Comment: inside or equal to? Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: Maybe need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280556/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-column-of-lists-for-those-that-contain-a-certain-item) ?

Answer (score 0):

To select the rows that contain `"#tourism"`, use [Panda's](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) `.loc` to subset your dataframe to desired observations

Suppose the column that has the hashtags is called `"hashtag_col"`

```
df.loc[df["hashtag_col"] == '#tourism',:]
```

#### Explanation

`boolean_array = df.loc[:,"hashtag_col"] == '#tourism'` returns a boolean array where `True` takes on values where the row value equals "#tourism".

`df.loc[boolean_array,:]` returns the subset of the dataframe for which the `boolean_array` is `True`.

### Alternatives

##### Using string functionality

Instead of using an exact match, you can also use Panda's string functionality to find values that contain the `#tourism` like so:

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,"hashtag_col"].str.contains("tourism"),:]
```

##### Implicit subset

Finally, you don't have to use `.loc` to explicitly select rows and columns but instead can use implicit shortcuts such as the below; however, in practice, this makes it harder for you and others to follow your code (check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc) as an example).

```
df[df[hashtag_col] == '#tourism']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.Series.apply) method

Here is the example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'tags': ['#hello', '#world', '#foo'], 'id': 1},
    {'tags': ['#foo'], 'id': 2},
    {'tags': ['#bar', '#baz'], 'id': 3},
])

print(df)
#                      tags
# 0  [#hello, #world, #foo]
# 1                  [#foo]
# 2            [#bar, #baz]

# Get only rows with tag #foo
tag = '#foo'
mask = df['tags'].apply(lambda arr: tag in arr)
print(df[mask])
#                      tags  id
# 0  [#hello, #world, #foo]   1
# 1                  [#foo]   2
```